the access point /org/freedesktop/networkmanager/AccessPoint/1053 was not in the scan list
I was curious if this community may be able to help me debug my Slackware machine. Mobile broadband works just fine but the internal wifi does not, producing the following message:

Is this a common error with the operating system? Are there any known ways to fix this message? Thank you so much for any help.
OS: Liveslak Mate

I think I have found the answer to this question (although someone please append this message if I am wrong).
It appears that Slackware does not configure wireless by default.
The best solution I have found is to run this command in the terminal:
netconfig

This command presents a dialogue to set up networking.
